# pytest does not await async fixtures

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi, motordriver

im working on FastAPI project with MongoDB connected with MotorDB.

Because motorDB and fastAPI is async I have figured that I have to make my tests async too.
I have a function to insert an object directly into Mongo:

```
async def mongo_async_test_insert_to_collection(db_name: str, collection: str, data: dict):
    client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(MONGO_DETAILS)
    database = getattr(client, db_name)
    collection = database.get_collection(collection)

    res = await collection.insert_one(data)
    return res
```

I have a fixture like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
async def add_mock_topic():
    result = await mongo_async_test_insert_to_collection(settings.TEST_DATABASE, "topics_collection", {
        "name": "TestName",
        "description": "test description"})
    return result
```

And a test like this:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_update_topic(add_mock_topic, async_cleanup_db):
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as ac:
        response = await ac.put(f'/topics/{add_mock_topic.inserted_id}',
                                json={"name": "Updated Name", "description": "Updated"})
    assert response.status_code == 200
    updated = await mongo_async_test_get_from_collection(settings.TEST_DATABASE,
                                                         'topics_collection', add_mock_topic.inserted_id)
    assert updated['name'] == "Updated Name"
```

The problem is that sometimes (when I run the whole test suite, about 30 tests in total, im using PyCharm runner) the response.status is 404. I figure that must be because the fixture coroutine was not awaited. I have expected the @pytest.mark.asyncio to await fixtures before proceeding with the test. The test runs ok when instead of using fixture, I use add_mock_topic as a function and await it inside the test.